# Does the re-release of Jedi Outcast and Jedi Academy affect the canon status of the games?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, video-games

[The news](https://www.ign.com/articles/2019/09/04/jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast-being-re-released-on-switch) recently came out the Star Wars Jedi Knight Jedi Outcast and Jedi Academy are being re-released on PS4 and Nintendo Switch. These games used to be canon (afaik) but no longer are since they are considered legends. Is this affected by the re-releases or are they still considered solely legends?

Comment: Re-releases of Legends materials are usually labelled as such in order to avoid confusion. I suspect it won't be any different in this case

Comment: @Valorum I agree, I'd imagine it's still non-canon but I think it would be good to have a canon answer (no pun intended) on this site.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.

From [the official Star Wars website](https://www.starwars.com/news/replaying-the-classics-star-wars-jedi-knight-ii-jedi-outcast):

> Star Wars video games have a rich history, steeped in decades of Legends lore, and a shining example of this is the beloved Star Wars Jedi Knight series.
>
> ...
>
> Come for the classic Doom-style gunplay, Jedi action, and Force puzzles; stay for the online one-on-one lightsaber duels in familiar Star Wars locations, like Cloud City and the Death Star. For years, Jedi Outcast has maintained a reputation for being one of the best Jedi-centric gaming experiences ever made. Game Informer magazine once deemed it “the most enjoyable and accomplished Star Wars game yet,” and it’s aged as gracefully as any fan could hope for. If you’re new to the realm of Star Wars Legends but you love video games, rediscover the Valley of the Jedi. Take your first step into a larger world.